# Fire a custom event with JavaScript (or jQuery) when my function finishes

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, events, eventemitter

Instead of having nested callbacks in JS, I would like to fire and listen to my own custom events. I don't need or want to access the DOM. Here's an example:

```
function doSomething(){
//...
$.trigger('finished-doSomething'); //fire the event 'finished-doSomething'
}

//when the event 'finished-doSomething' is fired -> execute the function in the second  param 
$.live('finished-doSomething', function(){
   alert("I finished-doSomething");
});
```

Would it be possible to do that with normal JavaScript code or with a library like jQuery? If not, what's a good approach to avoid nested callbacks?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, you can use custom events on some common element, say `document.body`.

```
// Subscribe
$(document.body).on('nifty.event', function() {
    // Handle it
});

// Publish
$(document.body).trigger('nifty.event');
```

[Gratuitous live example](http://jsbin.com/ujukuq) | [source](http://jsbin.com/ujukuq/edit)

Or for complete disconnection from the DOM, there are a couple of pub/sub jQuery plug-ins, [like this one](https://gist.github.com/661855).

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#foo').on('custom', function(event, param1, param2) {
  alert(param1 + "\n" + param2);
});
$('#foo').trigger('custom', ['Custom', 'Event']);
```

Source: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/