# Make button click more than once

Tags: click

Trying to make a simple single shooter game for my disabled son, I have the shooter working fine to shoot 1 bullet but can't seem to get it to fire the 2nd ,3rd, etc, when button is clicked. I am new to basic coding so an answer with actual line of coding would be helpful.
Thank you
this is my code
    
    
    
    Game tester

```
<style id="game-css">
#missile{
position:fixed;
top: 640px;
left:820px;
width:0px;
height:0px;
background:#ffffff;
}
#missile>div{
position:absolute;
top: -4px;
width:4px;
height:10px;
border-radius:10px 10px 0 0 ;
background:black;
}
#fire{
image:shooter.jpg;
width:140px;
height:190px;
}
</style>

</head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff">
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" scrollamount="15">
<img src="diamond.jpg"  /><img src="diamond.jpg"  />
<img src="star.jpg"  /><img src="diamond.jpg"  /><img src="star.jpg"  />
<img src="bomm.jpg" /><img src="diamond.jpg"  /><img src="star.jpg"  /></marquee>
<br><marquee behavior="scroll" direction="right" scrollamount="10">
<img src="diamond.jpg"  /><img src="diamond.jpg"  /><img src="bomm.jpg" />
<img src="diamond.jpg"  /><img src="diamond.jpg"  /><img src="diamond.jpg"  />
<img src="bomm.jpg" /><img src="diamond.jpg"  /><img src="star.jpg"  /></marquee>
<br><marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" scrollamount="20">
<img src="diamond.jpg"  /><img src="star.jpg"  /><img src="bomm.jpg" />
<img src="diamond.jpg"  /><img src="star.jpg"  /><img src="diamond.jpg"  />
<img src="star.jpg"  /></marquee>
<TABLE borderColor="#ffffff" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="100%" border="0">
<TR valign=bottom align=center>
<!--LEFT-->
<TD align=center width="30%" bgcolor="#ffffff"><font face="arial, helvetica" size="6"
color="#000000"><br><br><br><br><br><img src="rules.jpg"></font></TD>
<!--MIDDLE-->
<TD align=center width="40%" bgcolor="#ffffff"><font face="arial, helvetica" size="6" 
color="#000000"><br><br><br><br><br><img src="shooter.jpg" border="0" id="fire" alt="Click to  
shoot"></font></TD>
<!--RIGHT-->
<TD align=center width="30%" bgcolor="#ffffff"><font face="arial, helvetica" size="6" 
color="#000000"><br><br><br><br><br><img src="goal.jpg">
<br><br><img src="bullets.jpg"></font></TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
<div id="missile"><div></div></div> 

<script>$(document).ready(function(){

         $('#fire').click(function(){
         $('#missile').animate({top:-400},1500);

 });

 });

 </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Problem solved
Thank you NickR

Comment: what language do you used to implement it?

Comment: kindly mention which platform/languages you are using for building the Game

Comment: code is in jscript, someone had mentioned to me to "callback" the function but I am not familiar with that coding, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you add the code to the question.

Comment: ok code added to question, that was a task all in itself....lol

Comment: The problem here is because the animate function will always run on click, but you're never resetting the positing of `#missile`, so after it has run, it will *always* have a `top` property of `-400px`;

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
$('#fire').click(function(){
    $('#missile').animate({top:-400},1500, function() {
        // your callback
        $('#missile').css({top: 'auto', bottom: '-100px'});
    });
});
```

Then in your callback function you're resetting the position, and if you click again, then the animation will run again.

Comment: it looked like a good solution but when I put it in my code it shoots nothing not even 1 bullet

Comment: @Sha - Works fine here : http://jsfiddle.net/g9rUX/1/ although you need to expand the preview area quite a bit.

Comment: well when I go there and click on the shooter I get nothing, no bullets, just a white background with scrolling images

Comment: @Sha Try http://jsfiddle.net/g9rUX/2/ the bullet should be centred on that version.

Comment: ok after the 1st "click to shoot bullet" which does shoot 1 bullet the next "click to shoot bullet" only sits at the top of the screen it doesn't reload the bullet back to the shooting position

Comment: I got it Nick Thank you very much, I had to change "auto" to 680 to make it reload to the shooter, Thank you for taking the time

Answer (score 0):

A layman approach would be to repeat the code triggered upon a single click(event).

A single bullet getting fired by a piece of code for a single bullet(once), two bullets maybe repeat the code twice.

You can try firing a custom event when you function for first bullet finishes.
Please refer [Fire a custom event with javascript (or jquery) when my function finishes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164789/fire-a-custom-event-with-javascript-or-jquery-when-my-function-finishes)

This might help you for a start:

```
var isRunning = false;
document.getElementById('fire').addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (isRunning) {
        isRunning = false;
        //code for stop fire
    } else {
        isRunning = true;
        //code for start fire
    }
}, true);
```

This might help you to fire multiple bullets.

Thanx!

Comment: I tried duplicating the same code but for some reason it doesn't "reload" the shooter with the bullet to "refire" it.

Comment: I am a flex developer as far as my knowledge goes you can try binding the second "shoot" when the first event is over. Can you share the code??

Comment: use a callback or custom event. On basic google search I found "element.addEventListener" in js, I guess it works same as in actionscript(Flex). Try to imply this logic.

Comment: tried to put my code in the comment section but it says it is too long to post

Comment: Thank you Amar, kindly explain to me where and how I put this code into the one I have